# What happens if I copy and paste only the visual studio solution file to a different folder and open it from there?

Tags: visual-studio

It seems to work and load all the project files which are present in the original folder. How is this possible?

Comment: Why not try it and see rather than asking a simple question like this ? Also this type of question is off topic on here.

Comment: @deathismyfriend This *genre* of question would be on-topic, as it pertains to a tool used by programmers. Without more details though, yes, this is closable because it does not really ask a question.

Comment: Yes I should have specified that as it currently is that it is off topic.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it would work... sln file has relative paths to all projects, so moving just sln to arbitrary location should in almost all cases result in all links being broken.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at the .sln and .*proj files will be instructive. Here's the start of one of my .sln files:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
# SharpDevelop 4.4
Project("{12B76EC0-1D7B-4FA7-A7D0-C524288B48A1}") = "Mnemosyne", "Mnemosyne\Mnemosyne.ilproj", "{D80B3419-AE6B-44BB-8494-276E8513DAA2}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Tests", "Tests\Tests.csproj", "{0AFEC763-B9EC-44CB-8BFC-7F358B59F9BF}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
```

Here the bits `Mnemosyne\Mnemosyne.ilproj` and `Tests\Tests.csproj` are relative paths. In those files themselves also a snippet from Mnemosyne.ilproj:

```
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Constructor.il" />
    <Compile Include="Copy.il" />
    <Compile Include="Overloads.il">
      <DependentUpon>Overloads.tt</DependentUpon>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.il" />
```

Here `bin\Release`, `Constructor.il`, `Copy.il`, `Overloads.il` and `Overloads.tt` are also relative paths. Likewise in Tests.csporj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="nunit.framework">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NUnit.2.6.3\lib\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="UnitTests.gen.cs">
      <DependentUpon>UnitTests.tt</DependentUpon>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    </Compile>
```

Here `..\packages\NUnit.2.6.3\lib\nunit.framework.dll` `UnitTests.gen.cs` and `UnitTests.tt` are paths.

All of those paths are relative and point to files or folders within the folders, so this project can be copied in the sort of manner you describe and still work.

If you point outside of your folder, or if you have a full path, then it's possible you would break things.

You'd also want to be sure of config files, both web and application config files used when running an application, and the package.config files used by nuget. They also have paths that must be relative.

Generally speaking, you should make sure that your paths are relative anyway, and the various IDEs that target .NET (Visual Studio, SharpDevelop, MonoDevelop, Xamarin Studio) will favour relative paths for this reason. Being able to copy and move like this is always useful, and without it you wouldn't be able to use source control easily as every time you cloned a repository you'd have to change paths.

Answer (score 1):

This will work absolutely fine, as all of your solution data is stored in the solution file within the folder.

The only other issues could be:

- If you are using git, there will be a hidden folder where the git repo information is stored
- If your solution, code, build scripts, etc, have hard-coded paths, they will need to be corrected. (The paths in the project and solution folders are relative.)

Comment: If your solution has any relative project paths, that could also be an issue.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I was just adding that :)

Comment: If your solutions contains absolute paths, edit the .csproj (XML format) with a text editor and update the absolute paths.